# Excel - VBA : Simplify this If statement comparing cell to words

Tags: excel, list, vba, match

Easy question here.
I am currently using this in my program :

```
If LCase(inp_rng.Offset(1, 0).Value) = "street" Or LCase(inp_rng.Offset(1, 0)) = "ave." Then
score = score - 50
End If
```

It is obviously not clean but I can find a way to put it in one sentence only. What is the programming way of writing something like this:

```
If LCase(inp_rng.Offset(1,0).Value = ("street", "ave.", "road", "...", etc.) Then
'do something
End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Select Case statement instead:

```
i = LCase(inp_rng.Offset(1,0).Value
Select Case i
    Case "street", "ave.", "road"
        'do something
    Case Else
        'do something
End Select
```

Alternatively you can populate all possible answers in an array and search the array for a match.

Comment: Cases with the same outcome can be separated by commas eg. Case "street", "Ave.", "road" further simplifing this example.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Filter()` array function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164525(v=office.10).aspx